# Create an Android library project in NetBeans

Tags: android, netbeans, jar, android-library

How can I create an Android library project in NetBeans IDE? The build target would be a JAR for use in another Android project. I've seen the documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html for creating a library project in Eclipse, but I'm using NetBeans. I do not see an `isLibrary` property available in the properties for the Android project. If there is not a built-in way to accomplish this, how might I go about manually setting up an Android library project? Forgive me if this is a thick question.

Comment: Netbeans using maven to build the sourcecode so i think you have to write your own build.xml with the right dependencies. The isLibary property is a dirty hack to get the dependencies right at building the targets.

Comment: @Michele, so if I include all Android and other dependencies, and just import the JAR into my real Android application project, this should work? There is nothing magical about `isLibrary`?

Comment: i think there is nothing more, have you tryed it? doesnt it work?

Comment: @Michele I have not, I just wanted to make sure I was going down the right path before starting...

Comment: jep ok i unstand :-), i found this http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html#SettingUpLibraryProject perhaps useful to look up whats the real difference between a normal and libary project is.

Comment: @Michele thanks for the link, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans is using the standard android project layout (see [the features site](http://www.nbandroid.org/p/features.html)) and the standard ant-based build. This means that there is a `project.properties` file in the project's root. A library project has `android.library=true` in it, along with the android target version (and eventually other android library references). This file can be viewed and opened under `Important Files`. When cleaning and rebuilding, Netbeans behaves as if this is a lib project (does not create apk etc.)

Otherwise, you could use the SDK `android` tool (located in `$SDK/tools`) to generate the lib project on the [cmdline](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html) and then try to import it into Netbeans somehow.